# fixing a bug in while tokenizing a string

Tags: c

I'm trying to tokenize a string using the following code:

```
char dpal_path[]="s/s/test";
char sep ='/';
int i= 0;
int j = 0;
size_t length;
const char *token;
while (dpal_path[i] != 0)
{   
    if (dpal_path[i] == sep)
    {
        token = &dpal_path[j];
        length = i-j;
        j=i+1;
        printf("%.*s\n", length, token);

    }
    i++;
}

if(i == strlen(dpal_path))
{
    token = &dpal_path[j];
    length = i-j;
}

printf("%.*s\n", length, token);
```

The problem now the string "test" I can't tokenize it, I have to put at the end of the string "s/s/test/", I have to put a separtor at the end to tokenize test. There is a bug in the code but I can't fix it.

EDIT: I have fixed the above code, I hope this can be a correct code, please mention if its not correct or not.

Comment: Have you tried to step through your code line by line in a debugger? It usually helps in cases such as this.

Comment: Your code is also not actually doing anything.

Comment: I stepped through the code, but the code doesn't tokenize the last token in  dpal_path

Comment: And for the last one, it runs from `j` to the end of the string.

Comment: You can also use `strtok`.

Comment: @MicroVirus I modified the code so that it prints length and token, but still I don't get the last token

Comment: Tokenizers generally have to assume that a special case exists at the termination of the loop....just accept the end of the string as a token.

Comment: Yes, that's because after the loop the final token runs from `j` to the end of the string. Of course, `j` is only defined inside the loop, so you'll have to take its definition out of the `for`.

Comment: Think about what happens when the string ends. Where do you end up then? What would the values of `i`, `j` and `&dpal_path[j]` be (if `i` and `j` weren't local to the loop)?

Comment: Does this code compile?! How can `printf` call get `length` and `token` values, if they are declared locally in another block of code?

Comment: [This is not a question, it's a story](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/); please consider how you can [improve your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The value of i will be the last byte in the string, and j will point to the last token

Comment: @CiaPan I fixed it, please show how I should solve it

Comment: @MicroVirus How can I tokenize the last token If I know that j ==4 in the example above ?  there is a condition but what is it

Comment: @andre Correctly, so you need to add a special case after the loop to handle the end of the string.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I have fixed it, in the edit, is it correct now ?

Comment: @andre Now it works properly .

Comment: @ameyCU The problem now that I want to use the const char*token in another function, but its only working inside the if case

Comment: @ameyCU Is it possible to have a generalized token variable or should It be used in the two if statements, If I want to do work with it ?

Comment: @andre You can have a generalized token variable  that wont make any problem

Comment: @ameyCU how would I modify the code please to use that general variable ? to be processed everywhere, not only inside the ifs

Comment: @ameyCU it's only useful here if (dpal_path[i] == sep){  you can make it as answer and I will accept it

Comment: @andre  For clarity you mean using `token` or any other one ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90323/discussion-between-andre-and-ameycu).

Comment: @ameyCU yes I mean using token

Answer (score -1):

```
const char *input = "a/b/zzz";
char sep = '/';
const char *b, *e;

for(b = e = input; ; e++)
{
    if(*e == sep || *e == 0)
    {
        if(e != b)
            use_token(b, e-b);  // start and length

        if(*e == 0)
            break;

        b = e + 1;
    }
}
```